# Convert cURL response to variables

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am a noob at curl and xml, but I have searched this site and the web for an answer to this, and nothing I have found works.

I am sending XML using cURL and the recipient service is getting the data correctly and creating a response which I am receiving. The response is echo'd from `curl_exec` as

```
<TRANS>
    <HPAY>
        <ID>223</ID>
        <MLABEL>XXXX XXXX XXXX 9854</MLABEL>
        <DATE>11/06/2013 21:00:36</DATE>
        <SEN></SEN>
        <REC>sc</REC>
        <DEB>0.00</DEB>
        <CRED>10.34</CRED>
        <COM>2.00</COM>
        <MSG></MSG>
        <STATUS>3</STATUS>
    </HPAY>
</TRANS>
```

Now I need to turn these in to variables, and now I am scratching my head at how to do this.

Edit, tried pasting browser source here but it keeps changing it. However, to answer a previous comment, it is an xml response

Comment: Is the response XML and you're outputting it in the browser so it's hiding the tags? View page source to confirm.

Comment: What parts do you want to be separated? For simple splitting by whitespaces, you could use `explode(' ', $str);`.

Comment: Use simplexml or DOMDocument.

Comment: This is the browser source:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use `SimpleXMLElement`

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$details = array();
foreach($xml->HPAY->children() as $k => $v) {
    $details[$k] = "$v";
}
print_r($details);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 223
    [MLABEL] => XXXX XXXX XXXX 9854
    [DATE] => 11/06/2013 21:00:36
    [SEN] => 
    [REC] => sc
    [DEB] => 0.00
    [CRED] => 10.34
    [COM] => 2.00
    [MSG] => 
    [STATUS] => 3
)
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33387)

Comment: Using SimpleXMLElement is producing the following:

PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI Service_mb is not absolute

I am receiving the response from the service provider, a payment processor in this case.

Comment: Then the information you gave is not complete just added live demo

Comment: the header to the xml response is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><MoneyInResponse xmlns="Service_mb">

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the data with XML parser like xpath